Max voltage of a varistor
I am currently investigating the EN 61010 standard. I have to protect my circuit for transient overvoltages in CAT 3. This results in impulse withstand voltage peaks of 4 kV on the mains supply.
I need a varistor that can handle this voltage before breaking.
My input is a 230 VAC system. My AC/DC converter can accept max 528 VAC. So I want my varistor to kick in at around 275 VAC (I think).
I've been looking in alot of datasheets and I cannot find any information about a max transient voltage a varistor can handle before braking.
Am I missing something?
If I understand it correctly:
I need a varistor with a max Vrms of around 275 VAC. A clamping voltage of around 520 VAC.
Where can I find information about what the max voltage is that a varistor can handle before just brake. Which in my case would be 4 kV.

Just about any reasonable varistor will be destroyed if you put 4kV across it. The pulse duration, current, energy, power etc. will have to be limited.

You will also have an impedance between your 4 kV and the actual varistor, so 4 kV will not appear across it. In the IEC standard, the pulse generator impedance is listed. If you place it behind any chokes and whatnot you have on your AC input, the impedance will be even higher and your varistor will have to dissipate less energy clamping the impulse.

The Littelfuse Varistors - Basic Properties, Terminology and Theory AN9767.1 has the following instances of failure in TABLE 3. VARISTOR CHARACTERISTICS (IEEE STANDARD C62.33-1982 SUBSECTION 2.3 AND 2.4):




TERMS AND DESCRIPTIONS
SYMBOL




Rated Peak Single Pulse Transient Currents (Varistor). Maximum peak current which may be applied for a single 8/20µs impulse, with rated line voltage also applied, without causing device failure.
ITM


Rated Single Pulse Transient Energy (Varistor). Energy which may be dissipated for a single impulse of maximum rated current at a specified waveshape, with rated RMS voltage or rated DC voltage also applied, without causing device failure.
WTM


Rated Transient Average Power Dissipation (Varistor). Maximum average power which may be dissipated due to a group of pulses occurring within a specified isolated time period, without causing device failure.
PT(AV)M




As far I can tell the max transient voltage a varistor can handle isn't specified. Rather:

The varistor nonlinear V-I characteristic in conjunction with the profile of the applied transient gives the peak current and thus energy which has to be dissipated for one transient pulse.
The peak current and energy for one transient pulse which can be handled by a varistor without causing failure are specified.
The average power dissipated due to repetitive transient pulses without causing failure of a varistor is also specified.

